# Jenkins: executing windows cmd which call other cmd?

Tags: windows, jenkins, cmd

In my Jenkins job I would like to execute a windows cmd which is synced from source depot during build, and this cmd will call other cmds synced from source depot too. The cmd runs with error due to unable to find the other cmds with relative path. It looks like the root cause is I cannot set start location for the initial cmd in Jenkins job configuration, which is not workspace root in my case. Any ideas?

B.R.

Comment: It is expected that you have all your required sources in the workspace folder. This ensures smooth running even if the slave has to be changed. But in your case, if you have to run cmds from different paths, you have to change directory(cd) to that path(absolute in your case perhaps) first and execute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try cd to appropriate directory first:

```
cd %WORKSPACE% && <your command>
```

This is [Hudson Environment Variables](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project), should be for Jenkins the same.